# No module named amazon_linux_extras when running amazon-linux-extras install epel -y

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, docker

Here is my (simplified) Dockerfile

```
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html#images-create-from-base
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

# get the amazon linux extras
RUN yum install -y amazon-linux-extras

RUN amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
```

When it reaches the `RUN amazon-linux-extras install epel -y` line during the build, it gets

```
Step 6/8 : RUN amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
 ---> Running in dbb44f57111a
/var/lang/bin/python: No module named amazon_linux_extras
The command '/bin/sh -c amazon-linux-extras install epel -y' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I think that has to do with some python 2 vs. 3 stuff, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're correct, it's because `amazon-linux-extras` only works with Python 2. You can modify the `RUN` instruction to `RUN PYTHON=python2 amazon-linux-extras install epel -y`